# How to not return anything for a method with return type int

Tags: java, jdbc, methods

```
    public static int logIn(Statement stmt){
    int id;
    String pw;
    String select;
    boolean match;

    System.out.print("userID: ");
    id = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("password: ");
    pw = input.next();
    input.nextLine();

    select = "SELECT user_id, password FROM login WHERE user_id = " + id;

    try{
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        while(rs.next()){
            if(id == rs.getInt(1) && pw.equals(rs.getString(2))){
                match = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException logfail){
        logfail.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("could not print password");
    }

    if(match == true)
        return id;
    else break;
}
```

In my program, the user will input their login info. Then they will be faced with a menu in which they select options 1-7. Options 1-7 are just various queries that will be run on their own data.

My login function is to verify that they are who they are, as to give them access to their own data. If the verification passes, I return the id number in which they entered so that I may pass it into the other functions (1-7).

In my if-else statement, I want it to return the id number if the passwords matched and to return `null` if it failed.

I know that `int` can't be `null` but my return type for this method is `int` so what can I do?
For the sake of timely completion of my assignment, I'm going to return a value of 0 if things don't match to indicate that the login failed. But, more important to me is becoming a good Java programmer so I want to know:

1. Is there a better way to do this? and
2. Since there is, what can I do and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest change you can make is to return `Integer` and return `null`.  `Integer` is an object, that's why you can do this.

Alternatively, you could throw an exception if it is an error to not be able to login.  It probably isn't an exceptional case, so this may not be the best way.

Probably the best thing you could do is to not return an int/Integer.  Instead, have a class that represents the thing to do next.

Answer (score 3):

Returning zero, or a negative value like -1 is one possibility. You can also create a checked exception `LoginException` which is thrown in case of invalid login credentials. The pro of this approach is that you have a nice way to log fault login attempts within the `LoginException`.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you declare a function with a primitive type it must return a value or throw an exception.  You can use the wrapper types:  Boolean,Integer,Long,etc to return null because these are "real" objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you've declared a method of an int type, it must return an int. Simply declare/define an invalid_return variable which will be returned in case no match is found, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

When a method has a return type of `int`, then you *must* return an `int`. To indicate that an error occurred, you can either return an value which is otherwise invalid or throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not return from a method is to throw an exception instead. Returning error values like null or zero leads to buggy code when people forget to check for them. An exception is unambiguous and can't be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Really to be sensible you should separate your return numbers from you query by placing the two in different methods.
To return null, you need to return a class such as an ADT(Abstract Data type) from a method.
However that may be over-complicated when you can simply flag 0 zero as null with a variable of class Integer that you reset to null before each use, so if it is zero returned you only need put in an if-else to test the "Integer" variable as null or contains resetting to a number returned as int from the method.